# How to upload large files to cloudinary in react

Tags: reactjs, cloudinary

I am trying to uploading a video file of over 1GB to Cloudinary from my react app using the Cloudinary unsigned method but I  get this status response **"413 Request Entity Too Large"**. When I try to upload a file less than 100MB it works fine. Please can you suggest the best approach to achieve this?

Comment: Could you post a snippet of the code that uploads the file?

Comment: Could API may have restriction on file size. If that the case, you might want to make the file smaller (split or shrink it)

Answer (score 0):

It might be to do with Cloudinary filesize limit and not necessarily react

https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/202520592-Do-you-have-a-file-size-limit-

Answer (score 0):

You can use our `upload_large` method.  Please refer to https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360009586100-Upload-movie-video-with-large-size for more details.